# A train crosses a labeled bridge

Tags: code-golf, math, integer

Consider a bridge of length **B** formed by tiles labeled with the digits of the positive integers concatenated. For example, if **B** was 41, then it would look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425
```

Now imagine a train of length **T** crossing the bridge. The leftmost point of the train starts at position **X** (1-indexed). To get a better understanding of the problem, let's make a scheme of the event, with **B = 41, T = 10, X = 10**. The train is drawn using equal signs (`=`) and lines:

```
         __________
         |========|
         |========|
-----------------------------------------
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425
```

The train can advance, at each step, by sum of the unique tiles it is located on. For example, the tiles the train stands on above are: `[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]`, the unique (deduplicated) tiles are: `[1, 0, 2, 3, 4]`, and their sum is `10`. Hence, the train can advance by `10` tiles. We should draw it again and repeat the process until the leftmost point of the train has passed the last tile:

```
                   __________
                   |========|
                   |========|
-----------------------------------------
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425

Sum of unique tiles: 1 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 36. The train advances by 36 tiles...

                                                       __________
                                                       |========|
                                                       |========|
-----------------------------------------
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425

The train obviously crossed the bridge completely, so we should stop now.
```

Since the people inside are bored, they count the tiles the train has advanced each time. In this specific case, `10` and `36`. Summing everything up, the train has moved `46` before it passed the bridge.

---

## Task

Given three positive integers, **B** (the bridge length), **T** (the train length) and **X** (the starting position, **1-indexed**), your task is to determine how many tiles the train has moved until it crossed the bridge following the rules above.

- You can assume that:

  - **B** is higher than **T**.
  - **X** is lower than **B**.
  - **T** is at least **2**.
  - The train eventually crosses the bridge.
- All our standard rules apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

---

## Test cases

```
Input ([B, T, X]) -> Output

[41, 10, 10] -> 46
[40, 10, 10] -> 46
[30, 4, 16] -> 24
[50, 6, 11] -> 50
```

Another worked example for the last test case:

```
The bridge is of length 50, the train 6, and the starting position is 11.

          ______
          |====|
          |====|
--------------------------------------------------
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293

Unique tiles: [0, 1, 2]. Sum: 3.

             ______
             |====|
             |====|
--------------------------------------------------
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293

Unique tiles: [1, 2, 3, 4]. Sum: 10.

                       ______
                       |====|
                       |====|
--------------------------------------------------
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293

Unique tiles: [1, 7, 8, 9]. Sum: 25.

                                                ______
                                                |====|
                                                |====|
--------------------------------------------------
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293

Unique tiles: [9, 3]. Sum: 12.
                                                            ______
                                                            |====|
                                                            |====|
--------------------------------------------------
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293

Train exists the bridge. Total sum: 3 + 10 + 25 + 12 = 50.
```

Comment: Can we assume the train *does* cross the bridge eventually? For inputs like `(200, 2, 169)`, the train gets stuck on the `00` in `…9899100101102…`.

Comment: @Lynn A little late, yes, you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 20 bytes

```
ṁ←U¡S↓←moΣuX_⁰↓Θ↑ṁdN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxkdtE0IPLQx@1DYZyMrNP7e4NCL@UeMGIP/cjEdtE4EqUvz@//9v9t/U4L@hIQA)

Takes three arguments in order **T**, **B**, **X**.

#### Explanation

```
ṁ←U¡S↓←moΣuX_⁰↓Θ↑ṁdN
                 ṁdN    Build the list of digits of natural numbers
              ↓Θ↑       Take the first B digits, add a 0 in front
                        then drop the first X digits
           X_⁰          Get all sublists of length T
       moΣu             Map the sum of unique values of each sublist

   ¡S↓←                 Repeatedly drop as many elements from the start of the list as the
                        first element of the list says;
                        keep all partial results in an infinite list.

  U                     Take elements until the first repeated one
                        (drops tail of infinite empty lists)

ṁ←                      Sum the first elements of each remaining sublist
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>110</s> <s>105</s> <s>104</s> <s>103</s> <s>100</s> <s>97</s> 96 bytes

- Saved five bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder); removed unnecessary assignment, moved negation into available whitespace.
- Saved a byte thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder); golfed `[~-x:x+~-t]` to `[~-x:][:t]`.
- Saved a byte; golfed `...range(1,-~b)))[:b]` to `...range(b)))[1:-~b]`.
- Saved three bytes; golfed `[1:-~b][~-x:]` to `[:-~b][x:]`.
- Saved three bytes; golfed `[:-~b][x:]` to `[x:-~b]`.
- Saved a byte thanks to [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn); golfing the `while` loop to an `exec` statement.

```python
b,t,x=input();S=x;exec"x+=sum(set(map(int,''.join(map(str,range(b)))[x:-~b][:t])));"*b;print-S+x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BDoIwEETvfEXTC0WKEa0cSnriEzgiB2oaQaU0ZYnl4q9jkZh42GTeZHZnzQztoI9LITDGi6RAnei0mYBEeSlcrpy6YheLcerJqID0jSGdBhqG@/vQ6S@PYKlt9E0RGUVR5XjylnXFofaU453MjfUrSRm7xZdsJ19t91So4BeNwM589VCxBUMR0t8LX8NnlLsqA1xa1TzwwlKK0sM6AcsCdvink1eIecqCIwvOK2WeUi8/)

Comment: An alternative [105 bytes](https://tio.run/##Tc69DoMgEADgnacgLELERi110DL5CI7GQRpSaSoSxZQuvjpFmyYdLrnvcn/mbYdJ577mCCEvqKWOK21Wi0nleMO3xIHXoJ4SuqsoXcyXdcSLtHjsDVbaUoROj0npw4ud6dzru8QZTTZBCGlL0bUuzNkuCJg5jMQuaXy4Vkknb@i7vC53wLo6OiIe0d8TRwF5llGYpXsAVgCW/uscMsiCCpAzcNlVBGUh/QA) long solution.

Comment: [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7BDoMgEETvfAXhIqTYiKUesJz8BI/GgzSk0lQkiim99Nct2jTpYZN5k52ddS/fjzZfK4kQWhX1NEhj3eIxKWsZwLM3Dw3DRYlwkPMy4Fl7PHQOG@spQsf7aOzOs5/o1Nmbxoymb0UIaYRqm5Ay0TbCt9EAboqpQ0jrNZaVOugr@t6vxAawKveNRCb098NuoJUzClm2DeAF4Nk/naKCPFIBcg7OGxWRWJQf). `[~-x:x+~-t]` can be replaced by `[x-1:][:t]`

Comment: `exec"x+=sum(set(map(int,''.join(map(str,range(b)))[x:-~b][:t])));"*b` works for 96. (The train will never take more than `b` steps to leave the bridge, and that whole operation will amount to `x+=0` over and over once it’s left.)

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>106</s> 102 bytes

```
import Data.List
(b#t)x|x>b=0|y<-sum[read[c]|c<-nub$take t$drop(x-1)$take b$show=<<[1..]]=y+(b#t)(x+y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zcy7CoMwFADQ3a@4YIYEUXKp7ZR06tg/EIf4AIOPSBJpBP89Le3S0vUMZ1Bu7KcpRj2vxnq4Ka@Ku3Y@oU3qWTjCtZH82EXutrmyveqqtj5akS9bQ7wae/Cks2alIUf2gYa4wTykEBUWRV3LPXtXNGQ7i7PSC0joTAKwWr14IEBLTJEz5D/G/@3EUygZXr7t/LILQ4xP)

```
(b#t)x
   |x>b=0                 -- if the train has left the bridge, return 0
   |y<-sum[   ]           -- else let y be the sum of
      read[c]|c<-         -- the digits c where c comes from
        nub               -- the uniquified list of
            show=<<[1..]] -- starting with the digits of all integers concatenated
          take b          -- taking b digits (length of bridge)
         drop(x-1)        -- dropping the part before the train
        take t            -- take the digits under the train
     =y+(b#t)(x+y)        -- return y plus a recursive call with the train advanced
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 123 bytes

```r
function(B,T,X){s=substring
while(X<B){F=F+(S=sum(unique(strtoi(s(s(paste(1:B,collapse=''),1,B),K<-X+1:T-1,K)))))
X=X+S}
F}
```

Just implements the described algorithm.

R is quite terrible at strings.

```r
function(B,T,X){
 s <- substring                         # alias
 b <- s(paste(1:B,collapse=''),1,B)     # bridge characters
 while(X<B){                            # until we crossed the bridge
  K <- X+1:T-1                          # indices of the characters
  S <- s(b,K,K)                         # the characters from b
  S <- sum(unique(strtoi(S)))           # sum
  F <- F + S                            # F defaults to 0 at the beginning
  X <- X + S                            # advance the train
 }
 F                                      # number of steps, returned
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYqxDoMgFAB3vqKbj/BMytAOBhYGF0cdWK3BloSi9UE6GL@d2rvxbivzRdVlznFKfolgcEDLd9KUH5Q2H5/s@/LBgVWG761uBfRne0OO/pMdnE9aPNDpOlJyIBuD0xLCuJLTVcVRouHYqdoK2Qy1xI7/YVZb0R@sPcoMtyveUUpefg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>22</s>  21 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḣ⁵QS
RDẎḣ⁸ṫṫÇ‘$$ÐĿÇ€S
```

A full program taking three arguments - the order is **B**, **X**, **T** - which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjsWPGrcGBnMFuTzc1Qfm7Xi4czUQHW5/1DBDReXwhCP7gcymNcH///83NfhvaPjfDAA)**

#### How?

```
ḣ⁵QS - Link 1, calculate next jump: list of digits, bridge under and beyond train's left
 ⁵   - program's fifth command line argument (3rd input) = T (train length)
ḣ    - head to index (get the digits of the tiles under the train)
  Q  - de-duplicate
   S - sum

RDẎḣ⁸ṫṫÇ‘$$ÐĿÇ€S - Main link: number, B (bridge length); number, X (starting position)
R                - range(B) = [1,2,3,...,B-1,B]
 D               - to decimal list (vectorises) = [[1],[2],[3],...,[digits of B-1],[digits of B]]
  Ẏ              - tighten (flatten by one) = [1,2,3,...,digits of B-1,digits of B]
    ⁸            - chain's left argument, B
   ḣ             - head to index (truncate to only the bridge's digits)
     ṫ           - tail from index (implicit X) (truncate from the train's left)
           ÐĿ    - loop, collecting results, until no more change occurs:
          $      -   last two links as a monad:
         $       -     last two links as a monad:
       Ç         -       call last link (1) as a monad (get next jump)
        ‘        -       increment
      ṫ          -     tail from that index (remove the track to the left after train jumps)
             Ç€  - call last link (1) as a monad for €ach (gets the jump sizes taken again)
               S - sum
                 - implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 117 bytes

```
f=(B,T,X,g=b=>b?g(b-1)+b:'',o=0)=>X<B?[...g(B).substr(X-1,T)].map((e,i,a)=>o+=i+X>B|a[-e]?0:a[-e]=+e)&&o+f(B,T,X+o):0
```

A pair of recursive functions:

1. `f()` sums the train's moves.
2. `g()` creates the string of numbers.

**Less golfed:**

```
f=
(B,T,X,
 g=b=>b?g(b-1)+b:'',                       //creates the string of numbers
 o=0                                       //sum of tiles the train sits on
)=>
  X<B?                                     //if we're not past the bridge:
      [...g(B).substr(X - 1,T)].map(       //  grab the tiles we're sitting on
        (e,i,a)=>o += i + X > B |          //  if we've passed the bridge,
                      a[-e] ? 0 :          //  ... or we've seen this tile before, add 0 to o
                              a[-e] = +e   //  else store this tile and add its value to o
      ) &&
      o + f(B,T,X+o) :                     //recurse
  0
```

```js
f=(B,T,X,g=b=>b?g(b-1)+b:'',o=0)=>X<B?[...g(B).substr(X-1,T)].map((e,i,a)=>o+=i+X>B|a[-e]?0:a[-e]=+e)&&o+f(B,T,X+o):0

console.log(f(41, 10, 10));  //46
console.log(f(40, 10, 10));  //46
console.log(f(30, 4, 16));   //24
console.log(f(50, 6, 11));   //50
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP >= 7.1, 153 bytes

```
<?$s=substr;[,$p,$q,$r]=$argv;while($i<$p)$a.=++$i;$a=$s($a,0,$p);;while($r<$p){$x+=$n=array_sum(array_unique(str_split($s($a,$r-1,$q))));$r+=$n;}echo$x;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BDoIwFEQvM4sSioGFbkrjQYwh1RBpgqX8tooxXt1vCXFWs3gzzw@euT0i6JAuIZI6SXiJWYLOGoZuD/Uc7NgL2Ba@gNnpsoRVMBpBwMg684X6Q7RCbyylhtOGyLy6kO5ia8nZOfUiW7rgRxvF9gCqmmwschRoXapPfx0mLIqZ9zUfuGm@k492coEr9wM)

To make it compatible with lower versions of PHP, change `[,$p,$q,$r]=` to `list(,$p,$q,$r)=` (+4 bytes).

```
<?
[,$bridgelen,$trainlen,$position] = $argv;                  // grab input
while($i<$bridgelen)                                        // until the bridge is long enough...
  $bridgestr .= ++$i;                                       // add to the bridge
$bridgestr = substr($bridgestr,0,$bridgelen);               // cut the bridge down to size (if it splits mid-number)
while($position<$bridgelen){                                // while we are still on the bridge...
  $currtiles =                                              // set current tiles crossed to the...
    array_sum(                                              // sum of tiles...
      array_unique(                                         // uniquely...
        str_split(substr($bridgestr,$position-1,$trainlen)) // under the train
      )
    )
  ;
  $totaltiles += $currtiles;                                // increment total tiles crossed
  $position += $currtiles;                                  // set new position
}
echo $totaltiles;                                           // echo total tiles crossed
```